# Merging split zip file of a JAVA project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, split

My client sent me the source of a java program in split zip files (8 zip files!), because of the limitation in sending one zip file via Email. 
So now I need to merge all these files together and import them to eclipse.

I checked all these ZIP files, most of them have the same folders and files. 
Means that I can not unzip all of them to a folder... 
Can anyone help me how can I merge all of them together and how can I build the original project?

Answer (score 1):

This will probably work ... depending on the structure of the ZIP files.

1. Create a directory and 'cd' to it
2. For each ZIP file, unzip the file into the current directory.
3. Create a new ZIP file containing the entire directory tree based in the current directory.

It will definitely work in one sense.  The issue will be whether the structure of the combined ZIP will be appropriate for what you are trying to do.  And if the ZIP files "overlap" (i.e. there are two or mor files with the same path) then combining the ZIPs into one file *won't work*.

> I need to write a program or can I merge them in any other way?

Just use command line tools; e.g. on Linux you would use the `zip` and `unzip` commands.

Comment: Hi Stephen, 
Yes The structure of my files are the same. I mean in all ZIP files I have the same folders... What can I do?

Comment: *"What can I do"* - I have already explained.  See my steps 1 through 3.  (And of course, check your OS documentation for names and syntax of the zip / unzip commands that you need to use.)

Comment: You mentioned that "And if the ZIP files "overlap" (i.e. there are two or mor files with the same path) then combining the ZIPs into one file won't work." This is my case- all structure are the same.

Comment: Well if that is the case, some of the files will **replace** others in the final ZIP file.  Is that what you want / expect?

Comment: Yes, in this case my files will replace the others... But I was worry about if I replace the old ones, do I miss something from code?
Or if they have the same name, means they have also the same contents

Comment: I have no idea.  You will have to check them yourself.